# show just a number after the decimal point for a number in R

Tags: r, decimal-point

I can't find the way to show just 2 numbers after the decimal point for a number in R, I don't want round the number, I just want to display the number two as they are.

eg:

> 1.29964
>   I want to display: 1.29

Comment: change it to a string and take whatever characters you need?

Comment: While Josh's answer does the job,  I would warn you that this is a really **BAD** thing to do.  You're deliberately biasing the data to anyone who's looking at your output (or worse, taking the printed output and processing it further).  So unless you're in the Numbers racket and the first three digits are the daily winner :-), don't do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`trunc()` does almost, but not quite, what you are wanting. To generalize it a bit, write a function like this:

```
f <- function(x, d) {
   trunc(x*10^d)/10^d
}

set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(5)
x
# [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078
f(x,2)
# [1] -0.62  0.18 -0.83  1.59  0.32
f(x,4)
# [1] -0.6264  0.1836 -0.8356  1.5952  0.3295
```

Comment: This appears to break down for values of `x > 100` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- Yeah, good point. Floating point issues muck up the works pretty quickly with this approach (as becomes really clear if you set `options(digits=20)` or some such). If the OP wants this for printing textual output, they can sidestep most of those difficulties by wrapping the function above with `prettyNum()`, like this: `prettyNum(trunc(x*10^d)/10^d, digits=d)`. Also, +1 to your comment on the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Happy fun time `gsub` answer.  You could put together a function with a pasted regular expression.

```
adjust <- function(x, y) {
    p <- paste0("([0-9]+[.])([0-9]{", y, "}).*")
    Vectorize(gsub, USE.NAMES = FALSE)(p, "\\1\\2", x)
}
adjust(1.29964, 1:5)
# [1] "1.2"     "1.29"    "1.299"   "1.2996"  "1.29964"
lapply(0:5, function(x) as.numeric(adjust(1.29964, x)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1.2
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1.29
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 1.299
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 1.2996
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 1.29964
```

Comment: Just to be a Monday-morning pain in the ***, I'll note that all values of `y<0` are treated as `y ==1 ` .  :-)